# CSS Flex Layout: 2 columns out of non-hierarchal elements

Tags: css

I want to display the "right" and "left" elements in 2 columns. The right element should stretch vertically to the full height of the parent.  Standard solutions use an extra container for each column. However, in my situation, the columns have no semantic meaning, they are just for display. Further, since my project will have many instances of this structure, adding container elements would introduce a lot of mess.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='right'>
    <div class='left'>
    <div class='left'>
    <div class='left'>
    <div class='left'>
</div>
```

The under-appreciated "display:table-cell" almost works, but has some limitations, so that option is out. CSS "display:flex" is the only other potential solution that I can think of. I cannot find a working example, and my attempts have failed, so I hope that you can help me out. Thanks in advanced, -T

Answer (score 0):

`display:flex` is awesome, but browser support could be an issue. [Flex guide](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

What's wrong with something like the below?

[Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/ELSty/)

HTML

```
<div class="left">        
</div><!--
--><div class="right">    
</div>
```

CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
.left {
    background: #F00;
    width: 50%;
}
.right {
    background: #000;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a flexible container, its children can be stacked vertically or horizontally (not both) via `flex-direction`.  This is why if you want to use flexbox the `.left` divs should be wrapped in a containing parent.  The `.container` children are stacked horizontally and the `.left` children are stacked vertically.

Here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7aK9f/1/.

Here's HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class= "right">right</div>
    <div class = "left">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.container > .right {
    order: 2;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-flex: 3 0 0;
    flex: 3 0 0;
}

.container > .left {
    order: 1;
    background-color: #eee;
    -webkit-flex: 7 0 0;
    flex: 7 0 0;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container > .left > * {
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 0;
    flex: 1 0 0;
}

.container > .left > div + div {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0px #000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you DRD, you answered my question. I will have to add an extra container as you suggested.

Comment: Structurally and semantically it makes sense to add that extra markup.  The .left divs are different from the .right section and grouping these together is appropriate and technically useful.  Previous poster is correct about browser support: only modern browsers support the latest version of flexbox.